# Looping through multiple dataframes to perform multiple regressions and other diagnostics in R

Tags: r

I am currently working on how to loop through multiple data frames in R to perform a multiple regression within each frame 
and also a few diagnostic tests. I want to eventually have those outputs automatically saved to file so that I can analyze 
them all easier. My data concerns the airspeed and altitude at which aircraft flap and gear selections were made and what 
factors (airspeed and descent rates) influence those. I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am currently working on 
this on a MAC and will be transferring it to a windows computer later.

```
#Set my working directory

setwd("~/Desktop/R information/4.13.16")

#Define a path to where my csv files are

folder=tk_choose.dir(getwd(),"")

#Define a path to reset my working directory

directory=tk_choose.dir(getwd(),"") ##Same as the originally setwd()

#Change my wd so I can upload the files

 setwd(folder)
 srce=list.files(path = folder,pattern = "*.csv")
 list2env(lapply(setNames(srce,make.names(gsub("*.csv&","",srce))),read.csv),envir = .GlobalEnv)

#Create a list with all of the file names I just uploaded

 files=names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))

#Attempt to loop through the data frames looking to create a list of all of the variables (column names) 
#EXCEPT for those that contain BKT. 

for(i in files){bkt_i<-grep("BKT",names(i),invert = T,value = T);print(bkt_i)}

#Output
#character(0)
#character(0)
#character(0)
#character(0)
#character(0)
#character(0)

#How it looks if I specify the specific file. 
 bkt_i<-grep("BKT",names(CONF.1.10.8.csv),invert = T,value = T);print(bkt_i)

#Output
# [1] "File.No"              "Airline"              "Year.Month.of.Flight" "Departure.Airport"   
# [5] "Takeoff.Runway"       "Arrival.Airport"      "Landing.Runway"       "X9001_IAS"           
# [9] "X9001_HEIGHT"         "alt_10"               "lat_10"               "long_10"             
#[13] "flap_10"              "flap_lvr_10"          "ias_10"               "gear_10"             
#[17] "ivv_10"               "tla1_10"              "tla2_10"              "brake_10"            
#[21] "phase_10"             "gs_10"                "ias_avg_10"           "ivv_avg_10"          
#[25] "ias_min_10"           "ivv_min_10"           "ias_max_10"           "ivv_max_10"

#How I thought the loop should look all the way through the regression (eventually I am going 
#to add Durbin Watson Test,variance, VIF, scatterplots, and histograms and have everything 
#output to another file)

 for(i in files){
 bkt_i=grep("BKT",names(i),invert=T,value = T);
 y1_i=grep("IAS",bkt_i,value = TRUE); 
 y2_i=grep("HEIGHT",bkt_i,value = TRUE); 
 x_i=grep("ias|ivv",bkt_i,value = TRUE);
 reg.form_i=as.formula(paste(y1_i,paste("~",paste(x_i,collapse="+"))));
 lm(reg.form_i,data=i)}

#Output
#Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
#  <text:2:0: unexpected end of input
#1:  ~ 
#   ^

#How it all looks if I specify the file 

bkt=grep("BKT",names(CONF.1.10.8.csv),invert=T,value = T);
y1=grep("IAS",bkt,value = TRUE); y2=grep("HEIGHT",bkt,value = TRUE); 
x=grep("ias|ivv",bkt,value = TRUE);
reg.form=as.formula(paste(y1,paste("~",paste(x,collapse="+"))));
lm(reg.form,data=CONF.1.10.8.csv)

#Output
#Call:
#lm(formula = reg.form, data = CONF.1.10.8.csv)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)       ias_10       ivv_10   ias_avg_10   ivv_avg_10   ias_min_10   ivv_min_10   ias_max_10  
#  1.827e+02    3.195e-02   -5.799e-04    1.075e-01    3.702e-03    2.599e-02   -1.709e-03   -1.199e-02  
# ivv_max_10  
# -2.100e-03
```

Comment: You could merge these data frames and then use nested data frames. See [this blog post](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/), which also has a direct example on fitting a linear model on multiple data frames at once.

Comment: Each of the data frames have a different number of rows and columns so I don't think that nesting the data frames would work. The data frames are broken down by the altitude at which the configuration selection was made and what that selection was. I really have 30+ csv files, I'm just using 6 right now to get everything figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows for changing the working directory quickly (the only way calling and reading in a bunch of csv files is to make sure the path matches the working director), read in multiple csv files and then apply a function to run a multiple regression on all of the newly imported files (separate data frames). It looks for all of the variables that meet a certain criteria (grep functions) because all of the files have a different amount of variables. The MR results are stored in a list and then the summaries or the MR output can be called. Also by changing the lapply, a Durbin-Watson Test can be ran. Still working on incorporating other diagnostics.

Thanks @lmo for all of the help!!

```
setwd("~/Desktop/R information/4.13.16")
folder<-tk_choose.dir(getwd(),"")
directory<-tk_choose.dir(getwd(),"") 
setwd(folder)
srce<-list.files(path = folder,pattern = "*.csv")
list2env( lapply(setNames(srce, make.names(gsub("*.csv&","",srce))), read.csv),
          envir = .GlobalEnv)
myDataList <- lapply(srce, read.csv, as.is=T)
getFormula <- function(i) {   bkt <- grep("BKT", names(i), invert=T, value = T)  
  y1 <- grep("IAS", bkt, value = TRUE)   
  y2 <-grep("HEIGHT", bkt, value = TRUE)  
  x <- grep("ias|ivv", bkt, value = TRUE)   
  reg.form <- as.formula(paste(y1, paste("~",paste(x, collapse="+")))); 
  return(reg.form)` }

myRegResults <- lapply(myDataList, function(i) lm(getFormula(i), data=i))
summaries <- lapply(myDataList, function(i) summary(lm(getFormula(i), data=i)))
dwt <- lapply(myDataList, function(i) durbinWatsonTest(lm(getFormula(i), data=i)))
```